# I/O operator overloading error in C++

Tags: c++

please, perhaps, I am too tired cuz I can't seem to figure out why this input stream operator overloaded function is complaining..here is the .h declaration:

```
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in,  IntOperatorClass& intoperatorClass)
```

and here is the .cpp declaration:

```
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in,  IntOperatorClass& intoperatorClass)
     {
         in>>intoperatorClass.value;
         return in;
     }
```

the class has one private variable called value..

the class :

```
class IntOperatorClass{
     int value; //a value
     int arr[10];//an array value
 public:
     IntOperatorClass();//default constructor
     IntOperatorClass(int);//constructor with parameter
     IntOperatorClass(int arr[], int length);//an array constructor
     IntOperatorClass(const IntOperatorClass& intoperatorClass);//copy constructor
     IntOperatorClass& operator=(const IntOperatorClass& intoperatorClass);//assignment operator
     friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out,  const IntOperatorClass& intoperatorClass);//output operator;
     friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in,  IntOperatorClass& intoperatorClass);//input operator
     IntOperatorClass& operator++();//pre increment operator
     IntOperatorClass operator++(int);//post increment operator
     friend IntOperatorClass operator+(const IntOperatorClass intoperatorClassFirst , const IntOperatorClass intoperatorClassSecond);
     int GetValue(){return value;}
 };
```

is there something I am doing wrong because the compiler keeps complaining that the ">>" is not defined..

```
./op.cpp: In function 'std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, IntOperatorClass&)':
../op.cpp:77: error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'in >> intoperatorClass->IntOperatorClass::value'
../op.cpp:75: note: candidates are: std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, IntOperatorClass&)
```

Comment: What type is `value`? The compiler is saying there's no match to input **value** within your overload.

Comment: itz an int type.. I still don't get what the computer means by that..

Comment: What type is it *exactly*?

Comment: @henryjoseph, show your class definition.

Comment: I dont get your question now.. value is of type integer declared as a private field in the class.

Comment: Are you sure `value` is actually `int` and not some method to access the `int` (in which case you miss brackets: `value()`)

Comment: @henryjoseph Show `IntOperatorClass` in full. We need to know exactly what `value` is. Saying it is "of type integer" doesn't help much. You need to *show* us.

Comment: Right now, what you've given us resembles [this working example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4nO2H3%240).

Comment: I have updated the question to include the class now..

Comment: Looks as though you need `#include <istream>` in the .cpp file.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, Wow, geez. I didn't even think about that when adding it into my produced equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to include the appropriate header:

```
#include <istream>
```

Presumably you include some header that is including `std::istream` in some way but not pulling in the full contents of the `<istream>` header.

Comment: In C++03 `<iostream>` is not guaranteed to define `istream`, and in both C++03 and C++11 it adds (a tiny bit of) unnecessary overhead to initialize the standard streams, so `<istream>` is better

Answer (score 7):

Let's break the error down:

`../op.cpp:77: error: no match for 'operator>>' in

 'in >> intoperatorClass->IntOperatorClass::value'`

Firstly, the compiler is telling you the error is in `op.cpp` on line 77

I bet you that's this line:

```
     in>>intoperatorClass.value;
```

The next bit of the error is:

```
no match for 'operator>>' in 'in >> intoperatorClass->IntOperatorClass::value'
```

The compiler is saying that inside your `operator>>` it doesn't know how to use another `operator>>` to extract from an `istream` into your `value` member, which is an `int`

It then tells you that the only candidate it has that looks like an `operator>>` is your one, which extracts into an `IntOperatorClass` not an `int`.

It should have a whole lot of other candidates, for extracting into integers and doubles and strings and other types. The only way the compiler wouldn't know how to do that is if you haven't included the header that defines `istream` and its operators.

So do:

```
#include <istream>
```

at the top of the `op.cpp` file.

Presumably you'd included `<iosfwd>` somewhere, directly or indirectly, which declares `std::istream` as a type, but not included `<istream>` which defines it fully.

Comment: Thanks alot. would have accepted your answer but someone else did earlier before you but i voted you up . Thanks again